Find a list of four distinct vectors in $\mathbb{F^3}$ whose span equals $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F^3}:x+y+z=0\}$.
Where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
I had considerd the vector $(2,-1,-1)$ because $2+(-1)+(-1)=0$, and decided to create a list of scalar multiples of this vector. So something like $(2,-1,-1),(4,-2,-2),(6,-3,-3),(0,0,0)$ but obviously this doesn't span the desired set because it doesn't contain the triplet $(6,-4,-2)$. So I considered another list $(1,0,0),(-1,1,1),(0,-1,-1),(0,0,0)$ which seems more promising. But since span it is the set of all linear combinations I have to consider the vector $(1)(1,0,0)+(0)(-1,1,1)+(0)(0,-1,-1)+(0,0,0)=(1,0,0)$ which definitely not a member of the set  $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F^3}:x+y+z=0\}$. I'm quite lost and I don't know what to do, any help would be appreciated.

At a minimum, each vector in the spanning set should be in the set.  3 out of your 4 don't satisfy $x+y+z=0$.  So try some combinations of (x,y,z) that sum to zero.

Well, the dimension is $2$ and it is not hard to find a basis for the set. Then add in the negatives of the basis.

Note that you have 1 equation and 3 variables which tells us that there will be 2 degrees of freedom and hence a basis for this space is 2 dimensional. So we just have to find 2 basis vectors. While your choice $(2,-1,-1)$ could definitely be a basis vector, I think it is more intuitive to first ignore the $z$ component (set $z=0$). We then get vector $(1,-1,0)$ or some scalar multiple. We can do the same thing with the $y$ component to get $(1,0,-1)$. It is not hard to check if these are linearly independent. And sense we have 2 vectors these will be the basis of this space.
To find 2 more vectors, you can take linear combinations of the two above basis vectors. Also note that it might be tempting to do the same thing we did above for the $x$ component to get the vector $(0,1,-1)$, but this would not result in a linearly independent vector because $(1,0,-1)-(1,-1,0)= (0,1,-1)$.

Hi. Whynot take (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) , (0,0,1), (0,0,0)

@SophieClad the span of those vectors is all of $\mathbb{F}^3$, not the subset we want.
